# React : Stack columns when resizing window

Tags: css, reactjs, containers, react-bootstrap

I am trying to manage my containers in react so that they move nicely when the user is reducing his window's size. One thing I would like to manage, is to allow some components placed on the same row to stack upon each other if the window is reduced.

More precisely, let's say I have the following render, with 12 containers that fill the entire page :

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
          <div class="col-1">.col-1</div>
        </div>
```

Result (fits the whole screen):
[image]

What I am trying to do is to stack the containers on the right when the user decreases the size of the window. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: display: block. If you're using the bootstrap grid system it'll automatically do that for you on smaller viewports. As for having them on the right/left, there's a dozen ways to do that, from playing with float to using margins or negative margins, up to you. But for stacking, @media(max-width: **px) { .row { display:block;}}

Comment: Thank you, I first did not see that you said to use @media but now I understand. The only thing is that it seems to be all or nothing, the containers are either all aligned, or all stacked up? is there a way to only stack up the containers that are out of the window?